# Characteristic polynomial of $aA$-$bI$, $a,b \in$ $R$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

If $f(x)$ = det($xI-A$), what is the determinant of the matrix $aA-bI$.
I need to express my answer in terms of $f(x), a$ and $b$.

Comment: Do you know the size of the matrix $A$?

Comment: @B.Mehta it is just an $n$x$n$ matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\det(aA-bI) &= \det\left(a\left(A-\frac ba I\right)\right) \\
&= (-a)^n\det\left(\frac ba I-A\right) \\
&= (-a)^n f\left(\frac ba\right)\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks! This makes a lot of sense, for some reason I was trying to figure out $det (xI-(aA-bI))$, which was quite bothersome but I believe I was doing the wrong question because they weren't all that explicit in their question.

Comment: Note you can rewrite that as 
$$
\det(xI - (aA - bI)) = \det((x+b)I - aA)
$$

Comment: The new characteristic polynomial will be $a^n f(\frac{x + b}{a})$ except in the case of $a = 0$, where we get $f(x+b)$.